# c# replace timestamp value string of text in textfield

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio-2012

i currently have a textbox field, everytime a change is made, i add who it was updated by and what time

right now it keep appending that text

how can i find the line that says "LastEdited: ", and only replace the time stamp value?

this is what i do now
maybe someone can post me example of code how to grab the timestamp and replace it?

```
if (txtMemberNotesOriginally != txtMemberNotesChanged) {
            txtMemberNotes.AppendText("LastEdited: " + DateTime.Now.ToString() + " By: " + MyProgramName.Username + Environment.NewLine);
```

i am not an expert, so an example of code would bevery useful

i  do use this textbox to save other notes as well (which i wouldn't wanna loose)

can i do this

```
foreach (var line in txtMemberNotes.Lines) {
                if (line.StartsWith("Last Edited: "))
                {
                    txtMemberNotes.Text = txtMemberNotes.Text.Replace(line, "Last Edited: " + DateTime.Now.ToString() + " By: " + MyProgramName.Username + Environment.NewLine);
                }
                else 
                {
                    txtMemberNotes.AppendText("Last Edited: " + DateTime.Now.ToString() + " By: " + MyProgramName.Username + Environment.NewLine);
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to solve your problem seems to stop appending text and just set the text value.  No parsing is necessary, just overwrite the exiting values with your newer value.

```
if (txtMemberNotesOriginally != txtMemberNotesChanged) {
            txtMemberNotes.Text = "LastEdited: " + DateTime.Now.ToString() + " By: " + MyProgramName.Username + Environment.NewLine;
```

Comment: but i also have other notes in that field

Answer (score 0):

I guess theres always Regex if you really wanted:

```
string s = @"Some notes here etc etc..

              Last edited: 12/12/2012 12:00:00 AM";

Console.Write(Regex.Replace(s, @"Last edited: .*$", "Lasted edited: " + DateTime.Now.ToString()));
```

Or more specifically using your code:

```
txtMemberNotes.Text = Regex.Replace(txtMemberNotes.Text, @"Last edited: .*$", "Lasted edited: " + DateTime.Now.ToString());
```

Comment: can i maybe do the following?

   foreach (var line in txtMemberNotes.Lines) {
                    if (line.StartsWith("Last Edited: "))
                    {
                        txtMemberNotes.Text = txtMemberNotes.Text.Replace(line, "Last Edited: " + DateTime.Now.ToString() + " By: " + MyProgramName.Username + Environment.NewLine);
                    }
                    else 
                    {
                        txtMemberNotes.AppendText("Last Edited: " + DateTime.Now.ToString() + " By: " + MyProgramName.Username + Environment.NewLine);
                    }
                }

Comment: my problem is, how does it know its a "Line"? i have other code which replace /r/n to enviroment.newline when i set the data to the form

Comment: The $ in the regex tells it to anchor the result towards the end of the line. You could use this regex to make sure it's definitely on its own line: `^Last edited: .*$`. The ^ tells it to anchor it at the very beginning of the line.

Comment: this is not working for me, the text is 1 long string, to break to a new line i replace /r/n/ to enviroment.newline
i get the text from a API call, which is getting the info from a MySQL DB, so i have to use /r/n/ save it to DB for breaklines..